# The type cannot be converted implicitly System.Collections.Generic.List<anonymous> to System.Collections.Generic.List<Crypto>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```cs
public async Task<List<Crypto>> GetWithoutPrices()
{
    List<Crypto> cryptos = await _context.cryptocurrencies.Select(c => new
    {
        name = c.Name,
        id = c.Id,
        UpdateDate = c.updateDate
    }).ToListAsync();
    return cryptos;
}
```

```cs
public class Crypto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime updateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Error message:

> The type cannot be converted implicitly "System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string name, int id, System.DateTime UpdateDate>>" to "System.Collections.Generic.List<CryptoAPI.Modules

Answer (score 1):

You are currently returning as a List of anonymous type.

Instead, specify the type in `.Select()`

```cs
List<Crypto> cryptos = await _context.cryptocurrencies
    .Select(c => new Crypto
    {
        Name = c.Name,
        Id = c.Id,
        updateDate = c.updateDate
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

And would suggest using [PascalCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#pascal-case) naming for (public) properties.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but could you tell me how to specify my type in '.Select()'?

Comment: Check out the answer. You need `.Select(c => new Crypto { /* Properties */ })`